Why is a frame needed for a simple random sample?
In an introductory Statistics textbook I read that a simple random sample (SRS) was unique amongst sampling techniques in that a frame was required.  The textbook defines a frame as "a list which identifies all members of the population".  The textbook goes on to say "The principal liability of the simple random sampling technique is the necessity of forming the sampling frame.  There are sampling techniques that are designed to overcome the problem, one of which is called cluster sampling."
A related question was posed on this forum, but largely unanswered:
Obtaining a representative sample when there is no sampling frame?
The statement that a sampling frame is required for a simple random sample does not seem correct to me.
::EDIT::
I tried giving an example of a situation where a frame cannot be computed apriori, but instead of helping to illustrate my concern, the answers (while informative) focused on the flaws in my example.  So let me try to pose my question in words with no example:
The author seems to claim that a cluster sample is fundamentally different than a simple random sample because a simple random sample requires a frame (with the implication being that a cluster sample does not).
Can someone please suggest a situation that illustrates a situation where a cluster sample can be done, but a simple random sample cannot be done?
CAVEAT:  I know that a simple random sample is likely to be more costly than a cluster sample because the simple random samples are likely to be more separated geographically, for example.  Is the author saying anything more than that?

There's a category error here: the random numbers generated are not themselves the sample. The actual sample is drawn from the customer population. Your sample frame here is the first 150 customers entering the store.

Since my expectation is that the population size is 150, this is not an error.  To be even more sure, if my expected population is 150, then choose random numbers up to 200 (or whatever is 2 standard deviations above my mean population size).

@jbowman is correct. You have created a sample frame of 150 people. You are sampling from that frame. If you are only interested in doing inference about the customers who came in today then your sampling frame is the whole population. But that seems very odd. The people who came in today may be different from those who come in on any other day.

The problem is hypothetical.  I am trying to understand the difference between SRS and all other sampling techniques.  Please suggest another sampling technique that does a better job with the same knowledge, or suggest a different problem that illustrates the difference (cannot be done with SRS but can be done with another technique).

This problem is one of them.  If you wish to draw inferences about the people who enter your store today, you cannot sample from them as they enter using a predetermined sample size $n.$  The demonstration is that in such a sample, anyone coming to the store today must have the same chance of $n/N$ being chosen, where $N$ is the number who come.  Consider the effects of one last-minute customer: either you already sampled $n$ and this customer has zero chance of being sampled or you already sampled no more than $n-1$ and that customer has probability $1$ of being sampled.

An alternative technique is to select each customer independently as they arrive with probability $n/N,$ where $N$ is your initial guess of the total for the day.  At the end of the day you likely will not have a sample of size exactly $n/N$ -- but it's a perfectly fine random sample and can be used for inferences.

Having said all that, I would like to suggest that this post is just another of many appearing on CV that confuse the concepts of sample and population.  In the store example, the "population" is really a process in which people come to the store and you wish to make inferences about the properties of that process--either on a particular day or for a longer term.  We know it's not a real population because you can't construct a frame for it, not even hypothetically!

Cluster sampling requires constructing a frame only for the (randomly) selected clusters, rather than for the entire population.  The distinction is not one of "can" versus "cannot" be done, unless the clusters themselves are not known beforehand.

I would like to understand this better, and comments don't seem the best vehicle.  Is there any way to continue this conversation via email? (and then post a summary)  I'm cdonham _ AT _ gmail.com

I've tried to give an answer that addresses this in simpler language, and which gives the example you asked for, if that is helpful

Here is an example of "a situation where a cluster sample can be done, but a simple random sample cannot be done."
I want to do a survey of N=1,000 that is representative of all college students in the United States. To do this through a SRS would require that I take a list (the "frame") of all current college students in United States and randomly select 1,000 of them. The problem is that there is no such list anywhere. The US government doesn't have it, nor does anyone else. I could literally go and ask each school in the US to give me a list of all current students, but there is no way that is feasible. So there is no way to randomly select 1,000 cases from the population I wish to generalize about.
Note that this isn't just a problem with a "simple" random sample. It also means I can't draw a "stratified" random sample of all college students.
But I might still be able to draw a cluster (or multistage) sample that allows me to make generalizations about this same population. To do so, however I still need a "sampling frame" - actually I need a bunch of them. First, instead of trying to sample some number of students from the frame/list of all students I randomly select some number (say, 50) of colleges from the list/frame of all colleges. This is possible, because there is a list somewhere of the list of all (let's say 4 year) colleges in the US. So I take the list of all colleges and sample the first 50 of them. Then, at each of the 50 schools I have randomly selected I go to the school and ask me to give me a list of their current students. Let's say they all agree. Then at each of those 50 schools, I randomly select 20 students from the list of all students at that school.
Note that here we still need a frame to draw a sample, but we're just drawing different samples of different things. First we draw a sample of schools from the frame of schools, then we draw a bunch of samples of students from a bunch of different frames of students at particular schools.
In practice, everything is much more complicated, but this is the basic paradigm of when cluster sampling is feasible and SRS/stratified sampling is not, because there is no single list of all population members, but there are lists of "groups" that the members are in, and at each group you can get a list of the members at that group if you work hard enough. Think also of doing a sample of all hospital patients.

It seems to me that with a simple modification to your sampling procedure, I can turn it into a simple random sample.  I take a list of the enrollment numbers for the schools, for example let's imagine there are 15 million.  I then have a computer randomly select 1000 numbers from the 15 million (let's imagine numbers 1 - 40,000 correspond to UPENN, etc, so if I get 3 numbers in the range from 1-40,000, I know I need 3 students from UPENN).  Some schools will have students selected, others will not. ...

... Let's imagine I need 3 students from UPENN.  I do the same thing over again with their programs.  I know there are 1000 students in their engineering program, ...  I have a computer randomly choose 3 numbers from the 1-40,000 at UPENN, and see which program they are in.  I then ask the school for the FRAME data for those programs.   Haven't I achieved an SRS without ever having the identifying information for many of the schools, programs, etc?  In other words, no frame for the enter set -- only the subsets where students happen to have been selected....

... And since this is all generated randomly, every student had an equal chance to have been selected at the outset.

In your example you have actually created a frame of the whole US student pop, just a really unhelpful one.  You have a list that maps the natural numbers to the pop of all students. So you can draw a SRS. You just have to do a  bunch of extra work (reach out to each school where you sampled at least one student, and ask them to send you X random students) to actually get the contact information for each student you sample.

This approach ends up being way MORE logistically challenging than cluster sampling, since first you have to get the enrollment info for EVERY single school, and then you STILL have to convince many schools (way more than a cluster sample) to give you the info. It's important to note that the reason people do cluster sampling is because of the logistical and financial barriers to a SRS.  And here, you came up with a way to do an SRS that is still probably infeasible in practice. This is why cluster sampling is super common, and the approach you outline has (as far as I know) never been used.

My approach is admittedly much more costly (see "caveat" in the original post) and this conversation would never have happened if the author had focused solely on the fact that cluster sample saves money.  My problem was with the author implying that there were situations where an SRS could not be done where a cluster could (and you, and others, have resolved this for me) because this meant there was something I did not understand about a cluster sample.

If the textbook didn't make clear that money and logistical factors are the driving force in ALL sampling decisions then it is a bad textbook. After all, why do a sample at all, as opposed to just collecting data on the entire population? I might have phrased the bit "The principal liability of SRS is the necessity of forming the sampling frame" as "the reason SRS is often infeasible in practice is the necessity of forming the sample frame..." Sampling is all about getting as close to the theoretical ideal of a SRS given the intense constraints of the real world (like $$$ and access).

Let me propose an SRS of the undergraduate student population of the US without a frame.
The website NSCRC publishes the 2023 undergraduate enrollment numbers by state for the entire USA.  I downloaded the data.  There were N=15117830 undergraduate students.  I had Excel select n=10 random numbers in the range from 1 to 15117830.  The first student was 1300618.  I ordered the data from the states consecutively, so this student lives in Texas.  I do not need any identifying information from any state other than Texas to locate this student.  My claim is that I can continue to partition the Texas students by county or by school or ... and continue to narrow down who my student is until I need actual identifying information for a small subset of the entire population.  Repeat this process for the other students who were selected.
Again, since the student was randomly selected from the entire population, all students had an equal opportunity to be selected even though I did not have identifying information for the vast majority of students.

You describe a frame: it's a one-to-one correspondence between integers in 1, 2, ..., 15117830 and the students.  It's irrelevant that you can delay computing this correspondence until after the sample has been selected.

Ok.  So I don't need a list that identifies actual students. So how are the requirements for a cluster sample any different?  In a cluster sample, you only need identifying information for a subset of the population.  In my simple random sample, I only needed identifying information for a subset of the population.

Is the difference that you can cluster sample a population of unknown size where I need to know the size of the population to do a simple random sample?  (Is it meaningful to cluster sample a population of unknown size?)

In cluster sampling you might never even know how many subjects are in each cluster--only in the ones you sample.

Is it correct for me to say that you might select your clusters so that they are identifiable if not all members of your population are so?

I will be careful and just say I don't know what you mean by "identifiable," rather than guessing.  It might help to refer to a description of cluster sampling or, better yet, an account of an actual cluster sampling procedure: that might clear things up faster.

Many thanks to whuber, wright, lumley and others.
The answer that I understand best is this:

In cluster sampling, you don't need (might not have) the population size.
"In cluster sampling you might never even know how many subjects are in each cluster--only in the ones you sample." (whuber)

To do a simple random sample, you either need a list of all members of the population, or the possibility of identifying (e.g. name) any member of the population.
Without the population size and without the ability to partition the population (similar to not knowing the number of subjects in potential clusters), it is impossible to randomly sample the population.
Finally, I will say that I take as a given that a cluster sample is very likely to be cheaper than a simple random sample.  In a simple random sample, I don't need to go through the effort of naming every member of the population only subsets of the population that contain the random samples.  Still these subsets are likely to be much more disparate than a cluster sample. I was trying to understand if there were times when the simple random sample was impossible when a cluster sample could be done, and the answer this is "yes".
